# Convergence of $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} (1/N) \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{n}$ vs $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}/n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose we have a sequence $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots$ of real numbers. I am wondering what is the relationship between the limit
$$ L = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{n} $$
and the series
$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n}. $$
In particular, does $L$ exist with $L = 0$ if and only if $S$ converges?

I've been able to determine that the forward implication is *false* by the example below.

> **Example.** Let $a_{n} = 1$ if $n$ is prime and $a_{n} = 0$ otherwise. It is known that [the set of prime numbers has natural density $0$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/381456), so then $L$ exists and $L=0$. On the other hand, the [sum of reciprocals of primes diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes), so $S$ does not converge.

**My remaining question is**, is the backward implication true? That is, if $\sum_{n} a_{n}/n$ converges, does it follow that $L$ exists and is zero? I suspect this is true, but I can't seem to prove it in any straightforward manner.

Comment: look at Kronecker's lemma.